Retrieve/Export File List of Media URL in Wix
How can I retrieve a list of file names (URLS) of the media uploaded in my Wix Media.
I would need the list of file names in alphabetical order.
Given the amount of media I'm working with, I cannot simply copy the URL of individual file names. I need to obtain the list of file names in a bulk process.
I'm not all that familiar with codes and APIs so any assistance on implementing this would be greatly appreciated!
I've searched multiple forums but they date back a few years and don't work for me.
